# Mass multiplied by distance in exponential disk (galaxies)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

I model an exponential disk resembling a galaxy with mass density:

$\rho(r) = \rho_0 e^{(-r/h)}$

with $r$ the distance to the galatic center, $h$ the scale length of the galaxy and $\rho_0$ the initial mass density with units [kg/m^2] at $r=0$, and assume symmetry around $d\theta$.

I want to find the sum of each mass element of the galaxy multiplied by each of its distance from the center.

The cumulative mass of the exponential disk is:

$M(<r)=\int_{0}^{r} \rho(r) d^2r = \int_{0}^{r} \rho(r)r dr$

One way I came up to sum all the masses multiplied by their distances is:

$\int_{0}^{r} \rho(r)r^2 dr$

but isnt this multiplying the cumulative mass at every $r$ by its distance? The latter would not be what Im looking for.

Comment: Assuming this mass density is unit mass per unit area then you would integrate $r\rho(r)$ over the entire disk. In polar coordinates the area element is $r\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta$ so the integral would be $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}r^2\rho\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta$

Comment: According to your edit that $\rho$ is mass per unit length, that would have to be the mass density of a ring of radius $r$. Then you would just need to integrate $r\rho$ over all $r$. So the integral is $\int_0^{\infty}r\rho\mathrm dr$

Comment: @ErJio Thank you very much for your answer. I define mass density as mass per unit of area. Could you develop your first answer?

Comment: "...mass density with units [kg*m^2]... I define mass density as mass per unit of area." These two statements are inconsistent.

Comment: @hft Edited and corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, multiplying the cumulative mass at every r by its distance is not the same as summing each mass element of the galaxy multiplied by each of its distance from the center. To calculate the latter, you need to integrate the product of the mass density and the distance over the entire disk.

Here's the correct formula to sum each mass element of the galaxy multiplied by each of its distance from the center:

$$I = 2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \rho(r) r^2 dr$$

where:

- $I$ is the total sum of mass multiplied by distance
- $\rho(r)$ is the mass density at distance $r$ from the galactic center
- $r$ is the distance from the galactic center
- $h$ is the scale length of the galaxy
- $\rho_0$ is the initial mass density at $r=0$

This formula integrates the product of the mass density and the distance over the entire disk, effectively summing each mass element multiplied by its distance.

Comment: Precisely the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: Why both values (cumulative mass at every r by its distance, and summing each mass element of the galaxy multiplied by each of its distance) are almost the same for an exponential disk?

Answer (score 1):

> I am modelling an exponential disk resembling a galaxy with mass density:
>
> $\rho(r) = \rho_0 e^{(-r/h)}$
>
> ... and $\rho_0$ the initial mass density with units [kg/m^2] at $r=0$.

OK, so this is not a conventional *density* it is [an areal density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_density).

The areal density is the mass per unit area.

This means, for example, that the mass of the galaxy is:
$$
M = \int \rho(r) d^2r = 2\pi\int_0^\infty \rho(r) r dr 
$$

> I want to find the sum of the mass of the galaxy multiplied by its distance.

Just stick another factor of $r$ in the integrand:
$$
I = 2\pi\int_0^\infty \rho(r) r^2 dr = 2\pi\rho_0 \int_0^\infty e^{-r/h} r^2 dr\;.
$$

Methods to perform the integration [are well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Pi_function).

Comment: But $M(r)$ as you defined is cumulative mass (mass contained within radius r). I want to multiply each mass differential $dm$ by its distance, not cumulative mass up to radius $r$ by its radius $r$.

Comment: I have no idea what distinction you are trying to make.

Comment: It is not the same to sum the cumulative mass M(<r) which is the sum of mass within <r multiplied by its distance than to sum the differential mass times multiplied by its distance. I am looking for the latter, the equivalent to the sum of each star of the galaxy multiplied by its distance.

Comment: @Manuel I'm afraid you will have to wait for someone else to answer, since I still do not know what you mean.

Comment: Let me use the solar system as an example: It is not the same to sum each mass of each planet mutiplied by its distance, than to sum the mass within a certain distance multiplied by that certain distance. Which case is the one you answered?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't this multiplying the cumulative mass at every r
> by its distance? The latter would not be what I'm looking for.

No this is not what is happening in your working. For example, if we write the integral as a finite sum then the integral

$$ M=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty r\rho(r) rdr d\theta=2 \pi \int_0^{\infty} \rho(r) r^2 d r $$

would look like
$$ M=2 \pi \sum_0^{n} \rho(r_n) r_n^2 d r $$

so the mass that is multiplied with $r_n$ above is just $2\pi\rho(r_n)r_ndr$ which is the mass of an annulus of width $dr$ and not of the entire disk inside $r<r_n$. We do this for every $r_n$ and then sum the mass within each annulus $dr$ to get the mass of the entire disk.

Comment: What is $n$ in your equations?

Comment: $n$ is just the index of discretisation (and r/dr gives you the number of $n$'s).  It labels the radius: smaller $n$ means smaller $r$ and vice-versa. If you want the $r$ to go to infinity then $n$ also goes to infinity.

Comment: If I do this for an exponential disk, at large $r$, $M$ [kg*r] is almost the same as $M(<r)*r$. Does this make sense?

Comment: At large $r$ the density falls off exponentially in your approach. So most of the mass would be concentrated towards the center with negligible contribution from larger radius

Comment: But both values for a galaxy are almost the same for all $r$, why is this the case?

Comment: What values di you mean? $\rho$ and $r^2\rho$?

Comment: Both your definition of $M$ and $M(<r)*r$

Comment: I don't think I have $M(<r)*r$. I have $2\pi r \rho dr *r$ where $dM = 2\pi r \rho dr$. Therefore $dM$ (i.e. the term multiplied by $r$) is the mass contained only in the annulus $dr$